# Is it ok to ask the same question on multiple StackExchange sites?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, stackexchange

I have a question I think is on topic both here and on another SE site. Can I ask the question on both sites, or is this bad form? Should I link the two questions together if I ask them on both sites? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is bad form. If it can be asked on two different sites, chances are it's not a focused enough question. I suggest going into chat and seeing if maybe anyone in there can help you ask a more specific question that would be on topic either here or on the other site you're considering.

Comment: Wait, what about questions in the murky overlap gray area? I've had questions on Writers where I've been explicitly invited to cross-post on English Language & Usage. When did this become "bad form"?

Comment: In those cases, @LaurenIpsum, I believe the question's focus could be tailored to better address that site's audience. But generally, it's not encouraged. There are always going to be exceptions to the rule! :)

Answer (score 1):

As Aarthi mentions, yes.

However, if you think the two alternative approaches are different enough (for example, GD: "What's a good alternative to Myriad" vs SO: "How can I add Myriad font family as a @font-face") then it might be alright. Not the exact same question, though :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are plenty of questions that fit in multiple sites. One example is Photoshop Scripting. It is Javascript, but also Photoshop specific. Does that live in the Graphic Design site or Stack Overflow? There is also a [photography site on Stack](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) that has a lot of Photoshop related questions.

Ultimately, there should be a way to tag questions for multiple sites at a time, the same way you add multiple tags. I'm not saying to allow people to "push every button on the elevator", but if several sites have an established 'Photoshop' tag, you should be able to assign it, regardless of which SE site you are using. Naturally the community will police anything off topic per site anyway.